# Check date time in between current and -1 hour

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to send email for a certain schedule

My requirement is to send mail for the **1,2,4,7,14,21,28.. th days**  by comparing with the created date

Cron job will run for each 1 hour

the code which i have tried is given bellow

**My issue is mail sending 7,8,9,10,12,13... days**

Note:
If a user create a schedule on **6-12-2019**
Then notification need's to send on

**7-12-2019,
8-12-2019,
10-12-2019,
13-12-2019,
20-12-2019,
27-12-2019**

```
        $curDateTime->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone("UTC"));
        $curStrTime = strtotime($curDateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

        /**
         * to get the time less than one hour
         * Cron job will run for each one hour
         */
        $minusOneDateTime = new \DateTime('now -1 hour');
        $minusOneDateTime->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone("UTC"));
        $minusOneStrTime = strtotime($minusOneDateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

        $companies = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:BpUser')->getunResponsiveCompanyList($statusArray, $maxDays);
        foreach ($companies as $companyArray) {
            $company =  $em->getRepository('AppBundle:BpUser')->findOneById($companyArray[0]['id']);
            if ($company instanceof \AppBundle\Entity\BpUser) {
                $damage = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:BpDamage')->findOneById($companyArray['damageId']);
                $this->sendEmail($damage, $company);
            $dateCompare = $companyArray['compareTime'];
            $dateCompare->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone("UTC"));
            /**
             * To create the remainder times
             */
            $firstAlert = strtotime($dateCompare->modify('+1 day')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
            $secondAlert = strtotime($dateCompare->modify('+2 day')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
            $thirdAlert = strtotime($dateCompare->modify('+4 day')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
            $fourthAlert = strtotime($dateCompare->modify('+7 day')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
            $fifthAlert = strtotime($dateCompare->modify('+14 day')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
            $sixthAlert = strtotime($dateCompare->modify('+21 day')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
            $seventhAlert = strtotime($dateCompare->modify('+28 day')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

            /**
             * Check the remainder time
             */
            if( (($firstAlert >= $minusOneStrTime) && ($firstAlert <= $curStrTime)) ||
                (($secondAlert >= $minusOneStrTime) && ($secondAlert <= $curStrTime)) ||
                (($thirdAlert >= $minusOneStrTime) && ($thirdAlert <= $curStrTime)) ||
                (($fourthAlert >= $minusOneStrTime) && ($fourthAlert <= $curStrTime)) ||
                (($fifthAlert >= $minusOneStrTime) && ($fifthAlert <= $curStrTime)) ||
                (($sixthAlert >= $minusOneStrTime) && ($sixthAlert <= $curStrTime)) ||
                (($seventhAlert >= $minusOneStrTime) && ($seventhAlert <= $curStrTime))
               ) {
                    $company =  $em->getRepository('AppBundle:MyUser')->findOneById($companyArray[0]['id']);
                    if ($company instanceof \AppBundle\Entity\MyUser) {
                        $damage = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:MyDamage')->findOneById($companyArray['damageId']);
                        $this->sendEmail($damage, $company); //add data to mail queue
                    }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you clear your requirement, you have to send mail for 1,2,4,7 day of month right?

Comment: I believe the @OP wishes to send mail on the 1st, 2nd etc day relative to the date of creation rather than the static 1st,2nd etc of the month

Comment: @RamRaider  question has modified , need to add the schedule day + 1, 2.. etc

Comment: @Omi question has modified , no..

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

I have added days in array and then created alertDate from that day one by one and compared alertDate in between current date and -1 hour current date

```
<?php
$curDateTime->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone("UTC"));
$curStrTime = strtotime($curDateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
// to get the time less than one hour
// Cron job will run for each one hour
$minusOneDateTime = new \DateTime('now -1 hour');
$minusOneDateTime->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone("UTC"));
$minusOneStrTime = strtotime($minusOneDateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
//alert days
$alertDays = [1,2,4,7,14,21,28];
$companies = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:BpUser')->getunResponsiveCompanyList($statusArray, $maxDays);
foreach ($companies as $companyArray) {
    $company =  $em->getRepository('AppBundle:BpUser')->findOneById($companyArray[0]['id']);
    if ($company instanceof \AppBundle\Entity\BpUser) {
        $damage = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:BpDamage')->findOneById($companyArray['damageId']);
        $this->sendEmail($damage, $company);
        $dateCompare = $companyArray['compareTime'];
        $dateCompare->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone("UTC"));
        // To create the remainder times
        foreach($alertDays as $alertDay) {
            $alertDate =  strtotime($stop_date . "+$alertDay day");
             // Check the remainder time
            if($alertDate >= strtotime($minusOneStrTime) && $alertDate <= strtotime($curStrTime)) {
                $company =  $em->getRepository('AppBundle:MyUser')->findOneById($companyArray[0]['id']);
                if ($company instanceof \AppBundle\Entity\MyUser) {
                    $damage = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:MyDamage')->findOneById($companyArray['damageId']);
                    $this->sendEmail($damage, $company); //add data to mail queue
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: you have optimized the code .. i will test and approve the answer